# template show in multiple pages in liquid shopify

Tags: schema, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

How to use this condition for multiple pages?
Like index and product page.

```
{% if template.name == "index" %} 
 do something
{% endif %}
```

Comment: you mean, you create multiple templates?

Comment: if yes, you can assign the template to a particular page, and if you want to check it into other common files like `theme.liquid` `header.liquid` or `footer.liquid`

Comment: Then simply use `{% template.name == 'your custom template name ' %}`

Answer (score 1):

Try using something like this:

```
{% if template contains "index" or template contains "product" %}
  do something
{% endif %}
```